# Java File Marker API

Tags: java, file-io

I have a need for my application to be able to read large (very large, 100GB+) text files and process the content in these files potentially at different times. For instance, it might run for an hour and finish processing a few GBs, and then I shut it down and come back to it a few days later to resume processsing the same file.

To do this I will need to read the files into memory-friendly chunks; each chunk/page/block/etc will be read in, one at a time, processed, before then next chunk is read into memory.

I need the program to be able to mark where it is inside the input file, so if it shuts down, or if I need to "replay" the last chunk being processed, I can jump right to the point in the file where I am and continue processing. Specifically, I need to be able to do the following things:

- When the processing begings, scan a file for a "MARKER" (some marker that indicates where we left off processing the last time)
- If the MARKER exists, jump to it and begin processing from that point
- Else, if the MARKER doesn't exist, then place a MARKER after the first chunk (for now, let's say that a "chunk" is just a line-of-text, as `BufferedReader#readLine()` would read in) and begin processing the first chunk/line
- For each chunk/line processed, move the MARKER after the next chunk (thus, advancing the MARKER further down the file)
- If we reach a point where there are no more chunks/lines after the current MARKER, we've finished processing the file

I tried coding this up myself and notice that `BufferedReader` has some interesting methods on it that sounds like they're suited for this very purpose: `mark()`, `reset()`, etc. But the Javadocs on them are kind of vague and I'm not sure that these "File Marker" methods will accomplish all the things I need to be able to do. I'm also completely open to a 3rd party JAR/lib that has this capability built into it, but Google didn't turn anything up.

Any ideas here?

Comment: `mark()` and `reset()` are essentially there when you want to go backwards when reading. That won't fit your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Forget about markers. You cannot "insert" text without rewritting the whole file.

Use a [`RandomAccessFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) and store the current position you are reading. When you need to open again the file, just use `seek` to find the position.

Comment: Great suggestion @SJuan76 (+1) - I've never used `RandomAccessFile` before - how do I store the current position I'm at? Thanks again!

Comment: Outside the file you are reading. A .properties, a database, whatever.

Answer (score 0):

A Reader's "mark" is not persistent; it solely forms part of the state of the Reader itself.

I suggest that you not store the state information in the text file itself; instead, have a file alongside which stores the byte offset of the most recently processed chunk. That'll eliminate the obvious problems involving overwriting data in the original text file.

Answer (score 0):

The marker of the buffered reader is not persisted after different runs of your application. I would neither change the content of that huge file to mark a position, since this can lead to significant IO and/or filesystem fragmentation, depending on your OS.

I would use a properties file to store the configuration of the program externally. Have a look at the documentation, the API is straight forward:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html